# PHP Calendar Populated By mySQL Dates

Tags: php, mysql

I wonder whether someone can help me please.

I have a mySQL database which amongst many, contains a field which is made up of historical dates. In another field I hold a list of events linked to these dates.

I'm trying to find a PHP calendar where I can populate a 'Read Only' calendar which when the applicable date is selected, the event 'pops up in a table on the page.

I've trawled the internet for days looking for a suitable calendar, but all that I've seen require a 'from' and 'to' date which I don't have and as you would expect they have a lot of 'addition' and deletion' of dates and events functionality which I don't need.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps offer any guidance please on similar projects they've may have worked on, or, could recommend one of the many that are available.

Many thanks

Comment: Hi @SalmanA, I'd thought of this, but in all honesty I'm not skilled enough to do this. kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

a) Active Calendar - http://micronetwork.de/activecalendar/ (opensource and free)

b) PHP Calendar Class - http://www.klovera.com/php-calendar-class/ (costs $40)

For both you need to query your events from the database, and add them to the classes before the calendar can be generated

Answer (score 0):

You don;t think it is an issue with db design, better be two different table, one for dates and one for events.

Comment: Hi, I don't think so. I was trying to make my table design as simple as possible. Kind regards